# Call system command 'history' in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to using `os.system` function to call command 'history'
but the stdout just show that 'sh :1  history: not found'

Other example i.e. os.system('ls') is works. Can anyone can tell me why 'history' does not work, and how to call 'history' command in Python script.

Answer (score -1):

`history` is not an executable file, but a built-in bash command. You can't run it with `os.system`.